# Google visualization data grouping on String column

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[DB Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j84OA.jpg)

```
data_MONTHMONTHTEST = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('number','id');//0
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('string','month');//1
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('number','revenue');//2

var aggView_MONTHMONTHTEST_month =google.visualization.data.group(data_MONTHMONTHTEST, [1],[{'column':2, 'aggregation':google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number',label:'revenue'}]);


barChart_MONTHMONTHTEST_month = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(
{
    'chartType':'BarChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div_bar_MONTHMONTHTEST0',
    'options': barOptions_MONTHMONTHTEST_month ,
     dataTable:  aggView_MONTHMONTHTEST_month 
});
```

When Am drawing the chart month column values are not getting preserved. Rather it is drwing the chart based on alphabet order.

I've tried sort:disabled as part of options list,but no luck.

Can someone suggest how to preserve months order.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

We can disable the sort using **column index** following: After a day research I found an option to disable the column sorting

```
var aggView_MONTHMONTHTEST_month =    google.visualization.data.group(data_MONTHMONTHTEST123, [1],[{'column':2, 'aggregation':google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number',label:'revenue'}]);                   

aggView_MONTHMONTHTEST_month.sort({column: 1, sort: 'disable'});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. data.group already sorts the data so it doesn't work if you use disable after grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Use type `'number'` (vs. `'string'`) for the `'month'` column

```
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('number','id');//0
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('number','month');//1
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.addColumn('number','revenue');//2
```

Then use the formatted value to display the name.

Don't see your data load -- but the column value would change
From: `'March'`
To:   `{v: 2, f: 'March'}  // 2 for zero based months -- 3 works too`

or you can use a method...

```
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.setCell(row, col, 2, 'March');
```

or...

```
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.setValue(row, col, 2);
data_MONTHMONTHTEST.setFormattedValue(row, col, 'March');
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. In mycase Am adding the rows dinamically through an xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
It worked for me Bar chart.Here is the code
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
     <script src="Js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
     <script src="Js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>                                                                                
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
     <script src="Js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
          //google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
          //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        </script> 
---here is the CS file
    //GetDataperformance for JQgrid On load Event
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDataperformance()
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            string publisherid = HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountID"].ToString();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(publisherid))
            {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=203.115.195.52;user Id=appl;password=mcom007;database=mcom_ad_engine"))
            {
                //string StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_publisher_TotalPayout_Report", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisherid", publisherid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@istartdate", StartDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ienddate", EndDate);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                //Navigate to Login Page
            }
            return rows;
        }
```